# How do I plot a step function?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This should be easy but I have just started toying with matplotlib and python. I can do a line or a scatter plot but i am not sure how to do a simple step function. Any help is much appreciated.

```
x = 1,2,3,4
y = 0.002871972681775004, 0.00514787917410944, 0.00863476098280219, 0.012003316194034325
```

Comment: What do you mean by a step function?  Like a histogram?

Comment: @wim https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It seems like you want [`step`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html).

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4] 
y = [0.002871972681775004, 0.00514787917410944, 
     0.00863476098280219, 0.012003316194034325]

plt.step(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Well, if you don't want any vertical lines, have a look at `plt.hlines`. E.g. `plt.hlines(y, range(1,5), range(2,6))`

Comment: @Joe Kington: Sorry for the year-later comment. I'm a bit confused by this. Shouldn't the graph show 0.0028 between 1 and 2 and then jump to 0.051 at 2, and so on? It looks like step uses the next value along. (I'm thinking of a timeseries step, where the value is a at t0 and remains a until t1 when it changes to b and so on.) Is there a way to make step() behave in this way.

Comment: To answer my comment above, I've found that you can add the where='post' parameter to the step function. So in the example above, it would be: `plt.step(x, y, where='post')`

Comment: @JoeKington how to proceed if I would be given the bounds? I think that 1,2,3,4 are the reference points in your case

Answer (score 24):

If you have non-uniformly spaced data points, you can use the [`drawstyle`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_drawstyle) keyword argument for `plot`:

```
x = [1,2.5,3.5,4] 
y = [0.002871972681775004, 0.00514787917410944, 
     0.00863476098280219, 0.012003316194034325]

plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-pre')
```

Also available are `steps-mid` and `steps-post`.

Comment: Great. I used this for something else. Simple and precise.

Comment: [`drawstyle` documentation link](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_drawstyle). _"‘steps’ is equivalent to ‘steps-pre’ and is maintained for backward-compatibility."_

Answer (score 6):

### New in matplotlib 3.4.0

There is a new [`plt.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) method to complement [`plt.step`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html):

> [`plt.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) and the underlying [`StepPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.StepPatch.html#matplotlib.patches.StepPatch) provide a cleaner interface for plotting stepwise constant functions for the common **case that you know the step edges**.
>
> This supersedes many use cases of [`plt.step`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html), for instance when plotting the output of [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Check out the official matplotlib gallery for [how to use `plt.stairs` and `StepPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stairs_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-stairs-demo-py).

---

#### When to use `plt.step` vs `plt.stairs`

- Use the original [`plt.step`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html) if you have **reference points.** Here the steps are anchored at `[1,2,3,4]` and extended to the left:

  ```py
  plt.step(x=[1,2,3,4], y=[20,40,60,30])
  ```
- Use the new [`plt.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) if you have **edges**. The previous `[1,2,3,4]` step points correspond to `[1,1,2,3,4]` stair edges:

  ```py
  plt.stairs(values=[20,40,60,30], edges=[1,1,2,3,4])
  ```

[image: plt.step vs plt.stairs]

---

#### Using `plt.stairs` with `np.histogram`

Since [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) returns edges, it works directly with [`plt.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html):

```py
data = np.random.normal(5, 3, 3000)
bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 20)
hist, edges = np.histogram(data, bins)

plt.stairs(hist, edges)
```

[image: plt.stairs with np.histogram]

Comment: is it possible to emulate the `plt.stairs()`. My version of matplotlib does not contain it. I have also a bunch of code for python 2.7, so migrating is not that easy.

Answer (score 2):

Draw two lines, one at y=0, and one at y=1, cutting off at whatever `x` your step function is for.

e.g. if you want to step from 0 to 1 at `x=2.3` and plot from `x=0` to `x=5`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#                                 _
# if you want the vertical line _|
plt.plot([0,2.3,2.3,5],[0,0,1,1])
#
# OR:
#                                       _
# if you don't want the vertical line _
#plt.plot([0,2.3],[0,0],[2.3,5],[1,1])

# now change the y axis so we can actually see the line
plt.ylim(-0.1,1.1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it possible to use bin boundaries, like the `plt.stairs([1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])` , i.e between 0 and 1 the value is 1, between 1 & 2 is 2 etc. the step plot function refers (in my opinion) to midpoints, not to edges. The problem for me, is that `stairs` does not exist in python2

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `pylab.bar(x,y,width=1)` or equally `pyplot`'s bar method. if not checkout the [gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) for the many styles of plots you can do. Each image comes with example code showing you how to make it using matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone just wants to **stepify some data** rather than actually plot it:

```
def get_x_y_steps(x, y, where="post"):
    if where == "post":
        x_step = [x[0]] + [_x for tup in zip(x, x)[1:] for _x in tup]
        y_step = [_y for tup in zip(y, y)[:-1] for _y in tup] + [y[-1]]
    elif where == "pre":
        x_step = [_x for tup in zip(x, x)[:-1] for _x in tup] + [x[-1]]
        y_step = [y[0]] + [_y for tup in zip(y, y)[1:] for _y in tup]
    return x_step, y_step
```

Comment: Have been looking without success for an inbuilt function. Thanks! I had an issue (due to version?): TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable. I'm using Python 3.5. The function works after I change all zip for list(zip(...)).

Comment: @daniel Thanks for noting that! I wrote the code for python 2, so that explains the error.