# matplotlib how to fill_between step function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to shade regions of a plot where an input signal is high (value = 1). The region should remain shaded until the signal goes low (value = 0). I have gotten pretty close, following a number of examples:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axhspan_demo.html
[In a matplotlib plot, can I highlight specific x-value ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270981/in-a-matplotlib-plot-can-i-highlight-specific-x-value-ranges)
[How do I plot a step function with Matplotlib in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921296/how-do-i-plot-a-step-function-with-matplotlib-in-python)

The problem is that right now it is only shading directly under where the signal = 1, rather than to the *next* change to signal = 0 (step function). For example, in the image / code below, I would like the plot to be filled between 20-40 and 50-60 (rather than 20-30, and a spike under 40). How can I modify my code to achieve this? Thanks.
[image: output plot showing incorrect shading]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0,10,20,30,40,50,60])
s = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1,0])
t = np.array([25,24,25,25,24,25,24])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(x,t)
ax.step(x,s,where='post')

# xmin xmax ymin ymax
plt.axis([0,60,0,30])

ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()
# want this to fill until the next "step"
# i.e. should be filled between 20-40; 50-60
ax.fill_between(x, ymin, ymax, where=s>0, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You would have to do two calls to fill_between in this case. since saying to fill at 20,30,40 and 50,60 would be interpreted as fill 20 to 60. Since there is no point in that interval to not fill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a generator giving the intervals to fill.

```
def customFilter(s):
    foundStart = False
    for i, val in enumerate(s):
        if not foundStart and val == 1:
            foundStart = True
            start = i
        if foundStart and val == 0:
            end = i
            yield (start, end+1)
            foundStart = False
    if foundStart:
        yield (start, len(s))
```

The use this to get the intervals to fill in.

```
for start, end in customFilter(s):
    print 1
    mask = np.zeros_like(s)
    mask[start: end] = 1
    ax.fill_between(x, ymin, ymax, where=mask, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: thanks for the code. I was hoping it would be simpler (like a simple modification of the `where` clause in `fill_between()`, but I guess not. I will give your approach a try.

Answer (score 1):

Use `step = 'pre'` in ax.fill_between

```
ax.fill_between(x, ymin, ymax, where=s>0, facecolor='green',step='pre', alpha=0.5)
```