# How to fill between two lines near the intersection points using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been experimenting with building step graphs. It is tracking the score of teams over the course of a game. After a certain time period, points are scored and the line rises in a step fashion. I want to create a filling between the two lines. The issues is that there is no filling when these lines are intersecting. I tried to look at some help online, but they seemed to deal with step graphs where the steps were of equal size. Since, the spacing of each step is not equal in my graph, the program can't seem to detect that there is a gap between these two lines. I have the graph shown below and circled the regions where the filling is missing.

I want to be able to correctly fill these spaces with shading.
[image]

Here is the code that I have written in order to generate the graph. Please note that the overall code is still in a rough spot.

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")


plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'  # Choose your desired font family

times = np.array(times)
difference = np.array(difference)
away_score = np.array(away_score)
home_score = np.array(home_score)
y2 = 0

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(times, away_score, drawstyle="steps-pre", label="Kings")
ax.plot(times, home_score, drawstyle="steps-pre", label="Grizzlies")

ax.fill_between(times, home_score, away_score, where=(home_score >= away_score), step='pre', color='green', alpha=0.3)
ax.fill_between(times, home_score, away_score, where=(home_score <= away_score), step='pre', color='red', alpha=0.3)

plt.xlim([0, max(times)])
if away_score[-1] > home_score[-1]:
    plt.ylim([0, away_score[-1] + 5])
else:
    plt.ylim([0, home_score[-1] + 5])


ax.tick_params(axis='y', direction='out', length=6, width=2, colors='black', grid_alpha=0.5)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='--', linewidth=1)

ax.scatter(720, 18, color='red', zorder=5)
ax.annotate('100', (720, 18), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(15, -10), ha='center', fontsize=10)

plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
sns.despine(left=True)
sns.despine(bottom=True)


custom_xticks = [0, 720, 1440, 2160]  
custom_labels = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']  
ax.set_xticks(custom_xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(custom_labels)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe [how to fill_between step function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913347/matplotlib-how-to-fill-between-step-function) helps?