# How to make a line for the density of the distribution of my data in matlibplot (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve

How can I make a figure like the following one but with flat curve using matlibplot in Python?

[image]

Comment: view [step plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921296/how-do-i-plot-a-step-function-with-matplotlib-in-python)

Comment: view this [demo matplot](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a histogram to bin your data have a look at using a [KDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) for a continuous estimate of the probability distribution. There is an implementation using a gaussian kernel in [`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, 10000) #Generate some data

kde = gaussian_kde(data)

xplot = np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
plt.plot( xplot, kde(xplot), label='KDE' )
plt.hist( data, bins=50, histtype='step', normed=True, label='histogram' )
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Will produce the plot:

[image: KDE plot]

Note that when using KDEs the bandwidth of the kernel that you choose can have a very big impact on the representation of the data that gets produced, this is similar to the effect that the bin size would have when making a histogram. Both the scipy documentation that I linked to and the wikipedia page have good writeups on how to make this selection in a well motivated way.