# How do I plot a step function with Seaborn?

Tags: python, seaborn

I want to make a step plot using Seaborn similar to this [matplotlib example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921296/how-do-i-plot-a-step-function-with-matplotlib-in-python)

```
import seaborn as sns
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [0.002871, 0.0051, 0.0086, 0.005]
sns.lineplot(x,y)
```

Can I make use of `drawstyle='steps-post'` ?

The following does not work: `sns.lineplot(x,y, drawstyle='steps-pre')`

The result should look like this:
[image: step plot]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since further keyword arguments to `sns.lineplot` are passed on to matplotlib's plot function, you may directly use the `drawstyle` argument. The following works fine in seaborn 0.9.0 and matplotlib 2.2.2.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [0.002871, 0.0051, 0.0086, 0.005]
sns.lineplot(x,y, drawstyle='steps-pre')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or similarly with `sns.lineplot(x,y, drawstyle='steps-post')`

[image]

Comment: @Mr.T  In case of people asking "does not work" questions without specifying *in how far* it doesn't, there are three options (1) Start arguing about the SO guidelines in the comments (2) Closevote and move on (3) Answer and show that it *does* work. I chose (3) here, because reading that question I could not believe it not working and hence tried it out. I then thought that I could as well share my attempt because it may be useful to see (also for others) that in fact it does work as expected.

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder, if sns.lineplot(x, y) also does not work for them because they have seaborn 0.8.x

Comment: @Mr.T Could be. Best ask this question below the question.

Comment: It seems to work only with matplotlib 2.2.2 (and seaborn 0.9.0) , but not with 2.1.0 which I had previously.