# how to plot columns by column group in time series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
df= speed  status  timestamp      
     20     TRUE   9/10/2022..    
     30     TRUE   9/10/2022..    
     10     FALSE  9/08/2022..   
     ...
```

I want to plot the speeds by status through time, however the start-end times are not the same for TRUE and FALSE. I want them the start at the same point on the plot.

x-axis = time

y-axis = speed

TRUE and FALSE are denoted with different color lines on the plot. so comparing speeds of TRUE and FALSE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51513570/how-do-i-plot-a-step-function-with-seaborn

Answer (score 1):

`Seaborn` or `Plotly` packages do this out-of-the box better than matplotlib. you used matplotlib tag but didn't mention it in your question, so here's an answer using `Seaborn`:

```py
import seaborn as sns

df = your_data_loading

sns.lineplot(data=df, x='time', y='speed', hue='status')
```