# How to plot piecewise constant function in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, piecewise

I am trying to plot a uniform distribution having x and y values.
So the function looks like in this picture[image]

I need to plot this piecewise function in python, so I have tried to do it like shown below:

```
y = np.array([0, 0.04, 0.12, 0.16, 0.28, 0.32, 0.36, 0.44, 0.48, 0.52, 0.56, 0.72, 0.76, 0.8, 0.88, 0.92, 1])
x = np.array([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 24 ])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
ax.hlines(y=y, xmin=0, xmax=x, color='r', linestyles='--')
plt.plot(x,y)
ax.margins(x=0)
ax.set_yticks(y, [f'{yi:.2f}' for yi in y])
plt.show()
```

And it gives me [image]

However I need this plot to look like ‘steps’:[image]

Does anyone know how to optimize my code?

Comment: The function you need is `plt.step()`

Comment: Better yet, `ax.step()`: don't mix the `pyplot` and the object-oriented interface.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand how to use it. Can you please add a code comment?

Comment: Pretty sure you can can substitute `plt.plot(...)` with `ax.step(...)` and it should work. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-step-demo-py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I plot a step function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921296/how-do-i-plot-a-step-function)